# Show that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables taking values in $R^2$. Suppose that for all real numbers a and b, We know that
$P(X_1 ≤ a, X_2 ≤ b) =P(Y_1 ≤ a, Y_2 ≤ b) $,
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the two components of $X$, and similarly for $Y$.
 Show that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.
What is idea to get it?

Answer (score 0):

The accumulative distribution function $F(x,y)$ of a random variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ characterizes its distribution. Your hypothesis is telling exactly that the accumulative distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ are the same, so its distributions will be too. Usually this is actually the way to define that two random variables have the same distribution; that its accumulative distribution functions are the same.

The idea behind this is that the family $\mathcal{S}=\{(-\infty,a]\times(-\infty,b]:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ generates the $\sigma-$algebra of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so every measurable set $B\in\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e. every set for which you can compute $P(X\in B)$) can be expressed in terms of $\mathcal{S}$. The accumulative function $F$ of $X$ tells you the value of $P(X\in S)$ for every set $S$ of $\mathcal{S}$, so it follows that it determines $P(X\in B)$ for every Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so $X$.